# Swift 3 warning func collectionView instance method nearly matches optional requirement

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3

I am converting my project to Swift 3 in Xcode 8.1 and one of my collection view functions is returning a warning message indicating that the footprint has changed. The code is

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
```

and the warning is

> Instance method CollectionView(:CellForItemAtIndexPath:) nearly matches optional requirement collectionView(:canFocusItemAt:) of protocol UICollectionViewDelegate

I believe the warning is a red herring here. I looked up the API reference https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618088-cellforitem and I see

```
func cellForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell?
```

However, I am unable to find a declaration along these lines which won't result in a compiler error with a red dot.

edit:

After the answer below I added the datasource to my ViewController class as follows:

```
class MyController: UIViewController,
                         UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,
                         UICollectionViewDataSource,
```

then in `ViewDidLoad()` I added this `myCollectionView.dataSource = self`.

I now have this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
```

This View Controller is entirely constructed in code and had not implemented datasource although there was code for `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` which produced a compiler red dot after the datasource was added. This was updated to

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
```

Comment: try to set them as `public`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I believe the warning is a red herring here

Well, it isn't. Typically the way to treat the compiler is with respect; it usually knows considerably more than you do. Your https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618088-cellforitem is the red herring.

*This* is the function you want:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/1618029-collectionview

As you can see, the signature is:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
```

... which is subtly different from what you wrote originally.

Another thing to watch out for is that you must make this declaration inside a class declaration that *explicitly* adopts UICollectionViewDataSource. The only exception is if this is a UICollectionViewController, in which case it already adopts UICollectionViewDataSource — and in that case, the compiler will tell you to add `override` to your declaration (and you should obey).